# How to reduce congnitive complexity from 10 to 6 for a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a trouble reducing the cognitive complexity here for this function.I tried to separate the contents inside the `forEach` as another function and by calling it in `getCars` function but failed. Could anyone please help?

```js
const getCars = (cars, config, types) => {
  const {
    carName
  } = types;
  const carObject = {};
  const carsRange = () => {}
  let carRange = carsRange(cars);
  Object.entries(cars).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (key === 'sedan' && value) {
      const carRangeVal = value.split(' ');
      const year = carRangeVal[1];
      const model = carRangeVal[0].substring(1, 2);
      carRange = generateCarRange(year, model);
    }
    if (key === 'suv' && value) {
      const carRangeVal = value.split(' ');
      const year = carRangeVal[1];
      const model = carRangeVal[0];
      carObject['model'] = true;
      carRange = checkYear(year, model);
    }
    if (value) {
      carObject[key] = value;
    }
  });

  if (
    config.header === 'TEST A' ||
    config.header === 'TEST B'
  ) {
    carObject['carName'] = carName[0].id;
  }

  carObject['configName'] = config.header;
  carObject['contractStartDate'] = carsRange[0];
  carObject['contractEndDate'] = carsRange[1];
  return carObject;
};

console.log(getCars({}, {}, {}));
```

Comment: What does the input / output look like?

Comment: @JonasWilms output is a `carObject` which gets something like `{carName: 'Test', configName: 'Test A', contractStartDate: '01-01-2020', contractEndDate: '02-01-2020'}`

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could shorten the code in the .forEach function:

```
[year,model] = value.split(' '); // destructuring assignment
if (key === 'sedan' && value) {
  model = model.substring(1, 2);
  carRange = generateCarRange(year, model);
}
if (key === 'suv' && value) {
  carObject['model'] = true;
  carRange = checkYear(year, model);
}
```

It would be helpful to know the input data.

I have an inkling that you may be better off using `.map()` instead of `.forEach()`.

Why do you have two functions (`generateCarRange()` and `checkYear()`) to get `carRange`?

(I find it helpful to use Hungarian Notation to always know the type of my variables.)

Comment: Looks like this is what I was looking for. Let me try destructuring. I have these two functions `generateCarRange()` and `checkYear()`  in the utility which does some mock value generation stuff.